# Django not loading static files into assets file

Tags: django, templates, django-templates

I recently started a basic django project, i want to load an already made default template. This template has an assets folder with all the CSS, JS files etc

This folder, is later called in the templates, so for example i can have:

```html
<base href="../">
    // And a lot of static files being called like this:
<link href="./assets/scrollbar/css/scrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="./assets/somecss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
// And so on..

<script src="./assets/somejsfile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The problem with this is that none of the files in the assets are being retrieved. I know that the problem depends on where i put the assets folder, but i don't know how to solve that. I tried to add it to different parts of my project's structure but it doesn't work, since i only get a lot of errors like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/somecss.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Here is my **settings.py**:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

In this static folder, there is a basic css file i tested before trying this.

And here is the structure of my project:

```
 //MAIN FOLDER
    migrations
    ASSETS
    templates -> INDEX.HTML (where the assets folder is called)
    views, forms etc
```

Comment: There's a difference between a URL and a file system path. Having `./` in a URL doesn't make sense. Urls are mapped to file system locations by the web server, in the case you're on a development server, by the django `runserver`. `STATIC_URL` tells django what the URL prefix is for static files (and it gets added to urls if you use the `{% static %}` template tag). `STATICFILES_DIRS` tells django where to look for static files (aside the `static` app directories which are used by default), as long as you use the **django.contrib.staticfiles** app.

Comment: And don't put your static files inside the templates folder. Templates aren't static, they are used for rendering the final HTML responses. You'll eventually have conflict if you do this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @dirkgroten. Basically, my trouble is that, since i'm using a pre-made template, i would have to change basically every line where some static is called to the django way of calling static content

Comment: Well... yes and no. If all your static links start with `/assets/` then set your STATIC_URL to “/assets/” and your STATICFILES_DIRS to include the **assets** directory (which again should be outside of **templates**). That will work in development. But there shouldn’t be “./assets” in a pre-made template, that’s not how urls work and your template is bad if it does that. Also it makes it difficult to scale in production because it means you have to serve your static files from the same web server that serves Django (you won’t be able to use a sub domain and CDN for example).

Comment: And anyway it should be easy to replace all occurrences of your static urls starting with ./assets by the correct {% static %} url in one go. That’s what text editors do.

Comment: Got it! Thanks you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files) on this?

It is recommended to use the [`static` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-static)  to make the filesystem location of your static files independent from your URLs. Using this tag, your URLs would have to be defined like this:

```
{% load static %}
<link href="{% static 'assets/scrollbar/css/scrollbar.css' %}" 
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="{% static 'assets/somecss.css' %}"
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

You also need to define the setting [`STATICFILES_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS) because it looks like your static assets are not inside a default location inside an app of your project.

Comment: Yes, the problem with this is that, as i said i'm using a pre-made default template, so i would need to change a lot of lines of code to what you suggested. I know it's right, it's just that i was wondering if there is any other way to do that

Comment: You could use search-and-replace tools from your IDE (for example, `ctrl-r` in `PyCharm`) to do the bulk of the work for you; the documented way of using `static` will definitively be less trouble in the long run for you.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!